# Inserting PowerShell values in array into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

The code below in powershell will insert into a SQL Server table like

```
a aa aaa | b bb bbb
```

in one row, but I want

```
  a |   b
 aa |  bb
aaa | bbb
```

on 3 separate rows.

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = 
    "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$stringA = 'a', 'aa', 'aaa'
$stirngB = 'b', 'bb', 'bbb'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Server] (ServerName, UniqueID)
           VALUES ('$stringA[$i]','$stringB[$i]')"
    $Command.CommandText = $sql
    $Command.ExecuteReader()
}
$Connection.Close()
```

How can I manipulate my code to insert into 3 separate rows instead of 1 row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerShell does only simple variable expansion in strings. It doesn't expand complex expressions like index or property access the way you'd expect. An expression `"$stringA[$i]"` is expanded to the string representation of `$stringA` followed by an opening square bracket, the value of the variable `$i`, and a closing square bracket. The string representation of `$stringA` is all array elements joined by the `$OFS` character (Output Field Separator, by default a space), so you're inserting first `a aa aaa[0]`, then `a aa aaa[1]`, then `a aa aaa[2]`.

There are several ways of putting individual elements of an array into a string, e.g.

- string concatenation

  ```
  "... VALUES ('" + $stringA[$i] + "','" + $stringB[$i] + "')"
  ```
- subexpressions

  ```
  "... VALUES ('$($stringA[$i])','$($stringB[$i])')"
  ```
- the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx)

  ```
  "... VALUES ('{0}','{1}')" -f $stringA[$i], $stringB[$i]
  ```

However, in your particular situation I do not recommend using any of the above approaches, because all of them make your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

What you want to do instead is use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Server] (ServerName, UniqueID) VALUES (@foo, @bar)'
$command.CommandText = $sql
$command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@foo', $stringA[$i])
$command.Parameters.AddWithValue('@bar', $stringB[$i])
$Command.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Prepared statement is great. Didn't know about it earlier. Would definitely save a lot of fuss. Thanks for it Ansgar! :)

Comment: Thank you Ansgar for this A++ answer!!